# How do I put the button and text on the bottom right in html?

Tags: html, css

How do I put the button and text on the bottom right in html?
I want to place a button on the bottom right and a text next to it so that it looks like in online stores ...
I can't understand why there are 3 buttons on top and the last one on the bottom?

```css
.flex-middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  /* Цвет фона */
  color: #800080;
  /* Цвет текста */
}

bottombanner {
  display: table;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Лучшие в мире товары!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 align="center">Телефоны недорого</h1>
  <h2 align="center">Здесь вы сможете найти телефоны по низкой цене</h2>
  <hr>
  <p>
    <div class="flex-middle">
      <img src="C:\Users\Misha\Pictures\s-l640.jpg" width="200" height="200"><a>7000грн</a>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Купить">
      </p>
      <img src="C:\Users\Misha\Pictures\iphone-11-pro-max-gold.jpg" width="210" height="210" alt="36999">
      <a>3699грн</a>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Купить">
      </p>
      <img src="https://i.allo.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/524x494/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/0/_/0_59_16_1_1.jpg" width="200" height="200"><a>5499грн</a>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Купить" onclick="window.location.href='https://allo.ua/'">
      </p>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: -2%; position: inherit;">
        <img style="padding: 20px;" src="https://i8.rozetka.ua/goods/21350797/copy_huawei_p_smart_2021_128gb_green_5ffd6e36c99dd_images_21350797501.png" width="150" height="210">
        <span style="style=" vertical-align: 5px;><a>4999грн</a> </span>
        <p>
          <input type="button" value="Купить" onclick="window.location.href='https://cutt.ly/Sc5kIPN'">
        </p>
      <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the last of your product were in `div` because of this reason, last one was correct.
i put other product in `div` and add `text-align: right;`. now `button` & `text` are bottom and right.

```css
div {
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Лучшие в мире товары!</title>
</head>
<style>
   .flex-middle {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   }
   body {
   background: #fff; /* Цвет фона */
   color: #800080; /* Цвет текста */
   }
   bottombanner {
   display: table;
   }
   .col-sm-3 {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   button{
   position: absolute;
   right: 10px;
   bottom:  10px;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <h1 align="center">Телефоны недорого</h1>
   <h2 align="center">Здесь вы сможете найти телефоны по низкой цене</h2>
   <hr>
   <p>
   <div class="flex-middle">
   <div>
      <img src="C:\Users\Misha\Pictures\s-l640.jpg" width="200" height="200"><span>7000грн</span>
      <p><input type="button" value="Купить"></p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="C:\Users\Misha\Pictures\iphone-11-pro-max-gold.jpg" width="210" height="210" alt="36999">
      <span>3699грн</span>
      <p><input type="button" value="Купить"></p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="https://i.allo.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/524x494/602f0fa2c1f0d1ba5e241f914e856ff9/0/_/0_59_16_1_1.jpg" width="200" height="200"><span>5499грн</span>
      <p><input type="button" value="Купить" onclick="window.location.href='https://allo.ua/'"></p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: -2%; position: inherit;">
   <img style="padding: 20px;" src="https://i8.rozetka.ua/goods/21350797/copy_huawei_p_smart_2021_128gb_green_5ffd6e36c99dd_images_21350797501.png" width="150" height="210"> <span style="style="vertical-align: 5px;><span>4999грн</span> </span>
   <p><input type="button" value="Купить" onclick="window.location.href='https://cutt.ly/Sc5kIPN'">    </p>
   <div>
```